# Clicking on two Subsampling scale images at the same time will crash Android

Tags: android, debugging

After clicking to two Subsambling scale image views... and when I click to both of them at the same time, I'm getting this error:

```
09-18 12:37:17.807  22777-22777/... E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: ..., PID: 22777
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
        at android.support.v4.widget.ViewDragHelper.shouldInterceptTouchEvent(ViewDragHelper.java:1004)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onInterceptTouchEvent(DrawerLayout.java:868)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1873)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2230)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1973)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2230)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1973)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2230)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1973)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2069)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1515)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2531)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2017)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8004)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4136)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3990)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3548)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3598)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3567)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3674)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3575)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3731)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3548)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3598)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3567)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3575)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3548)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5817)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5797)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5768)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5897)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:176)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:5870)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5916)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:542)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5246)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:780)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:596)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/idContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <com.davemorrissey.labs.subscaleview.SubsamplingScaleImageView
        android:id="@+id/idImage"
        android:background="@color/gsd_bg_darkest"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/idProgress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>
```

The code:

```
// uri is a string with the URL
// the view, is the view where are the images. The setBusy will delete the spinner from it


private SubsamplingScaleImageView.OnImageEventListener createLoadingListener(final View side){
        return new SubsamplingScaleImageView.OnImageEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onReady() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onImageLoaded() {
                setBusy(side, false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPreviewLoadError(Exception e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onImageLoadError(Exception e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTileLoadError(Exception e) {

            }
        };
    }

photoL = (SubsamplingScaleImageView) sideLeft.findViewById(R.id.idImage);
photoR = (SubsamplingScaleImageView) sideRight.findViewById(R.id.idImage);

photoL.setImage(ImageSource.uri(uri));
photoL.setOnImageEventListener(createLoadingListener(sideLeft));
```

Have I found a bug on the Android Code or what should I do to find out where is actually the problem? Any hint (also only to clarify the question) are really appreciated.

Comment: Could you please post the code with the image click listener? What did you use to subsample the images: a library or the default image view?

Comment: Please add your code here

Comment: adding, please wait :)

Comment: do you think that's enough?

Comment: are you shure that this is the complete stacktrace? i donot see any code in the trace of your own namespace `com.davemorrissey..` is there any "caused by" missing in the stacktrace?

Comment: that's the reason why I've put a bounty on it.. no idea of where the code crashed. Hopefully is in the part that I've added. If you have an idea to spot out the actualy part that crashed, I would make a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a bug of the library. Commenting this line solved the problem:

https://github.com/filnik/subsampling-scale-image-view/commit/b1ba2c3cbd0b095a90c463a682743e3e5dab88cf